# Why did this actor play a cameo role in Deadpool 2?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

In Deadpool 2, there is a brief moment (couple of seconds) where we see X-Men  trying to hide from Deadpool when he is in the mansion.

However, in this scene we see James Mcavoy in the role of Prof. Xavier.

Assuming Deadpool is not in 80's or 90's (he is well in 2010's) then shouldn't Patrick Stewart have played this role?

Or should it be assumed that James Mcavoy has taken 100 % of this role and now he will play the older version too?

So how is this timeline matching?

Comment: You mean in end credit scenes when he was time traveling ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma No, in movie. When Beast quietly closes the door behind Deadpool.

Comment: I don't think Deadpool fits in any timeline. Deadpool is that Marvel movie that is only for entertainment purpose - with silly jokes and sometimes real-time references. E.g if you remember, in the beginning Deadpool mentions about Logan's death. So in all, Deadpool doesn't fit in any MCU's timelines.

Comment: Funfact: Patrick Stewart had stated (before DP2's production began!) that the only time he would return to the franchise [would be in Deadpool!](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/03/03/patrick-stewart-professor-xavier-deadpool-return/) What a missed opportunity :(

Comment: Have you noticed that when Deadpool wears the Cerebro helmet, he complains that "it smells like Patrick Stewart"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So how is this timeline matching?

## It doesn't.

It's just a two part joke thrown in due to fortunate timing and the availablity of the current X-men actors.

It was joke from the first Deadpool movie that the school was empty even though it should be overflowing with recognisable mutants.

At the time this was due, mostly, to the character "permissions" being tightly controlled and budget issues but now this is not such an issue.

However, the previous iterations of the X-men actors aren't available (Jackman a possible exception) but fortunately, the new versions, it so happened, were.

So...

### A scripted joke got enhanced...

> Director David Leitch told us how the shot came together. “That was interesting because Simon Kinberg was filming X-Men: Dark Phoenix in Montreal at the same time we were doing Deadpool,” he told Den of Geek. **“So this was in the script but we were always wondering how we were going to be able to pull it off.** The set supervisor, Dan Glass, who did the Matrix films, he came up with this idea of doing a composite, and getting the plates to match.
>
> “So we shot our side here, and we sent the measurements and the camera positions and things up to Simon's team on Dark Phoenix, and they shot the plate for that there,” continued Leitch. “Then we put the two together. So actually it turned out to be easier than we thought. If we would have had to get all those people in the room it probably wouldn't have happened.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/deadpool-2/273617/how-that-deadpool-2-x-men-cameo-happened)</sup>

Comment: When you say 'Marvel (mostly) has these back...' in terms of rights... you are aware both *X-men* and *Deadpool* aren't owned by Marvel Studios, right? they're both owned by Fox and have always been in the same rights stable, hence Wade Wilson's inclusion in the Wolverine film.

Comment: Are you aware that Marvel has concluded a deal ....to buy Fox. https://www.vox.com/culture/2017/12/14/16738852/disney-fox-marvel-acquisition-x-men-superhero and http://uk.businessinsider.com/disney-fox-deal-means-x-men-deadpool-fantastic-four-join-marvel-cinematic-universe-2017-12

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional is definitely right here, neither Deadpool or the X-Men were officially owned by Marvel Studios at time of filming or Release. There is a deal on the table but It has not been finalised and the rights to the Fox owned marvel characters are nowhere near Marvel Studios hands. The actual reason for there being no X-men in the X Mansion in the first movie is because Fox were reluctant to make Deadpool and as a result there was a low budget. This was rectified in Deadpool 2 due to the critical success of the original so they were able to get more X-men for the cameo.

Comment: Well, yes... but no. *DISNEY* have *started* the acquisition of Fox, but that's irrelevant entirely... Deadpool and X-men have never had any rights restrictions in their cross pollination, and at the time of production Disney weren't necessarily in the frame.

Comment: Yes, Disney's deal is not finalized and Fox head says they will proceed as business as usual until it is. Deadpool has been thought of being in it's own timeline/universe. It's just has permission to "touch" on events in X-Men films being "meta" in nature, unlike like Legion and the Gifted that are in parallel universe further removed from knowlege of the main X-Men films. It's a way to tell different kinds of X-Men stories and not be beholden to each other.
http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/01/26/deadpool-writers-explain-how-the-movie-fits-into-the-x-men-timel/

Comment: @Paulie_D, you've edited your answer but still missed the point! 'Right's issues' were *never a factor* in their crossover!

Comment: Also although it is unclear if Legion will come back for a third season, due to this unexpected exrta episode recently annoucned,  Noah Hawley has stated that he does want to try and bring in Patrick Stewart at some point and has not shyed away at aknowledging that this ALTERNATE verseion of Xavier, is David's father. He has been alluded to often. So even though there are liscensing issues between Fox Tv vs Fox Film, the idea of it is on the table...

Comment: @Paulie_D, I give up! you were so close to getting an up-vote, but your answer is just...incorrect! There are no rights/permissions issues, they have already crossed over in the past. It was about *timing*.

Comment: Oh well, I tried. Repcapped already for the day...anyway! :)

Answer (score -6):

I think you've missed the joke.

Deadpool did not see the X-Men. **Deadpool saw the actors** (and filming equipment).
The next X-movie will not be contemporary of Deadpool.

If I remember correctly the next X-movie will be set in the 80/90

Comment: In that scene, Deadpool don't see anyone. Instead he complaining to Colossus "Where is everyone?".

Comment: You can also refer to this article which confirms X-Men are trying to avoid Deadpool in that scene:

http://www.denofgeek.com/us/movies/deadpool-2/273617/how-that-deadpool-2-x-men-cameo-happened

Answer (score -8):

Yeah, " assuming Deadpool is not in 80's or 90's". 
You could also assume Deadpool is on the moon and ask "If he's on the moon why there's air and trees?"

We didn't know Deadpool timeline. UNTIL that scene set DP in the X-men continuity and the 90's. This scene was directed BY "Dark Phoenix" director in postproduction to place Diddy Pe in universe.

DirtyPolly is known to not be aligned with one time and timeline. Or Universe. Or even publisher franchise. This anchor is something that don't need to be very crucial for this particular character.

Comment: Don't forget Colossus is with DP in that scene, how do you explain that?

Comment: In scene, yes. In same frame? No. Think about that like Tyler Durden

Comment: Are you proposing that Colossus is imaginary in that scene?

Comment: No, the X-men. Or not imaginary. he joke in D1 was that in so big mansion there are only Teenage and Ironballs. In d2 we see they are there just not in Deadpool vision. Kind like "Others" (or Dark Souls) or those old comedy bits when people look for each other and enter the same room at different time so they don't notice each other.